# Bower refuses to install from github fork

Tags: git, github, bower

*bower.json file*

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/foo/bar",
  "authors": [
    "...."
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "my-github-forked-repo": "git@github.com:stoplion/my-github-forked-repo.git#~2.1.4"
  }
}
```

I've forked a Github repo, made my own commits on it, and would like to install it via `Bower`.

Reading the [Bower docs](http://bower.io/#install-packages) it appears you can point the package name to a github endpoint (which I've done like the above).

The issue is that the repo that is downloaded via Bower **has none of my changes**. I've double checked my Github repo and the changes are in my master. My path to my fork in my bower.json is correct. I've ran `bower cache clean` to make sure it was fetching a fresh copy.

Anyone run into this problem and know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to pull in a forked repo via Bower you'll have to add a `commit hash`, or a `tag` or `branch` to the end of the path like so:

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/foo/bar",
  "authors": [
    "...."
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "my-github-forked-repo": "git@github.com:stoplion/my-github-forked-repo.git#master"
  }
}
```

I used the commit hash method to avoid, if in the future I choose to merge in the original repo, tags clashing. This worked for me.

Comment: Any idea why that is so? Which version is bower taking if there's no hash at the end? I created my own tag after pushing changes, but it's still not taking that one.